# rollup.js: How to disable output?

Tags: rollupjs

I'm trying to use the rollup JS API. [rollup.rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#rolluprollup) doesn't require me to specify the `output` option but it appears [rollup.watch](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#rollupwatch) does for some reason.

Here's what I've got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import * as rollup from 'rollup';

async function main() {
    const watcher = rollup.watch({
        input: 'src/main.ts',
        // output: {
        //     dir: 'dist'
        // }
    })

    watcher.on('event', event => {
        console.log(event);
    })
}


main().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
})
```

It's saying:

```
{
  code: 'ERROR',
  error: Error: You must specify "output.file" or "output.dir" for the build.
      at error (file:///somepath/screeps/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:10380:30
)
      at Object.write (file:///somepath/screeps/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/rollup.js:1
8594:24)
      at file:///somepath/screeps/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/watch.js:7083:86
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at Task.run (file:///somepath/screeps/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/watch.js:7083:6
3)
      at async Watcher.run (file:///somepath/screeps/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/watch.
js:7003:17) {
    code: 'MISSING_OPTION'
  }
}
```

I should be able to get what I need out of the event emitter though -- I don't want to write it to disk. How do I disable that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's a [`watch.skipWrite`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#watchskipwrite) option.